# How to execute AngularJS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I am working with ASP.NET for last few years, so I'm comfortable working with MVC,JavaScript, Visual studio etc.

Now I have a small project that I need to take care of. It was developed in AngularJS. I have installed Visual Studio Code so I can start & debug the application. I understand I need to create a launch.json file, however I'm not sure what goes into this file.

**launch.json**

```
            {
            "version": "0.2.0",
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "name": "Launch",
                    "type": "node",
                    "request": "launch",
                    "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\manager\\angular\\js\\app.js",
                    "stopOnEntry": false,
                    "args": [],
                    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "preLaunchTask": null,
                    "runtimeExecutable": null,
                    "runtimeArgs": [
                        "--nolazy"
                    ],
                    "env": {
                        "NODE_ENV": "development"
                    },
                    "externalConsole": false,
                    "sourceMaps": false,
                    "outDir": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Attach",
                    "type": "node",
                    "request": "attach",
                    "port": 5858,
                    "address": "localhost",
                    "restart": false,
                    "sourceMaps": false,
                    "outDir": null,
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "remoteRoot": null
                }
            ]
        }
```

**app.js file**

```
    // Declare app level module
    var main = angular.module('eng-im', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngCookies',
        'toaster',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'angularSpinner',
        'engrafa.directives',
        'engrafa.controllers',
        'rt.encodeuri',
        'searchbar',
        'base64'
    ]);
```

When I hit F5, I see debugger starts at "angular.module()" method but then when I step through it throws an exception.

```
> node --debug-brk=40967 --nolazy manager\angular\js\app.js 
Debugger listening on port 40967   
c:\code\manager\angular\js\app.js:32  
var main = angular.module('eng-im', [           ^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined   
        at Object.<anonymous> (c:\code\manager\angular\js\app.js:32:12)  
        at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)  
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)  
        at Module.load (module.js:344:32)  
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)  
        at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:442:10)  
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Questions
1) AngulerJs application has app.js file & index.html file. What should be the value for "program" property in launch.json?

2) Do I need to install any extension for AngularJS?

Comment: The only thing you need to run a angular app is serve the html file that loads the angular.js library and start your app. Any other request to your local server must deliver the exact path called in the request. 
The problem with your approach is that your app.js is trying to use a script that is not loaded yet ( angular).

Comment: You need to include the actual AngularJS library: https://github.com/angular/angular.js

Comment: the application is already developed & running in production for quite some time now. That means i am assuming references are correct. Im not sure which IDE other developers have used. I was trying to use Visual Studio Code. What is the preferred IDE for AngulerJS in Windows

Comment: Ok...so you need to load your index.html file and not your app.js. But in orther to this to work the webserver that vscode starts need to be able to delivery correctly the files that index.html will try to load.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend not even using the `launch.json` approach, and, you don't **need** extensions to run your AngularJS application in VSCode.

The easiest way I found is to install `http-server` via npm and use it to serve your application.

First, run `npm install http-server` from a terminal window in the project's root directory.

Next, add `http-server -o` to the start script in your package.json file. (The `-o` opens the served application in your browser automatically.) More options can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

An example package.json might look like this:

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "myAngular1App",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts":{
    "start": "http-server -o"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

Finally, run your application with `npm start` from a terminal window.

Comment: Great! And how to make so that it automatically server index.html if present?

Comment: @Phate based on the docs it looks like you would use `http-server ./index.html -o` in the script: start command above. You may have to play around with that a bit to get it right. Here is the docs for more help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server .... I'm referencing this part: `http-server [path] [options]`

Comment: OP, Did this work for you? If so, please accept the answer and help others.